# Showing Error Updating CheckBox lIst Value "Index was out of range"

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have Two Check Box one is Check Box and Another one is checkbox List it working properly while adding  value of checkbox list but while updating value of check box it show me error of "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index" I am not getting why this error show 
Here my code

```
if (e.CommandName == "EditShift")
                {
                    string[] arg = e.CommandArgument.ToString().Split('$');



                    ddlShiftname.Text = arg[0];
                    txtstarttime.Text = arg[1];
                    txtendtime.Text = arg[2];
                    ddlIndicator.Text = arg[3];

                    string iRefNo = arg[4];
                    titlename.InnerText = "Update Shift Management";
                    btnAddShift.Text = "Update shift";

                    DataTable dtShiftManage = new DataTable();

                    dtShiftManage = objShift.GetShiftByRefNo(iRefNo);

                    foreach (DataRow dr in dtShiftManage.Rows)
                    {


                        ChkDays.Items[Convert.ToInt32(dr["WeekDay"])].Selected = true;

                    }


                }
```

please help me out from this !!

Comment: What is value of `dr["WeekDay"]`?

Comment: in week day i have all count of checkboxlist ... when user select all day check box at that time it  check all checkbox list which contain name of week

Comment: Then make sure `ChkDays.Items` contains that `dr["WeekDay"]` value

Comment: it taking value of 6 days but at the time of 7th day it show me error

Comment: May be `7` is not available in the Item List

Comment: i check out.. it is there..